# What is the correct way to use vert.x web when serving dynamic content?

Tags: vert.x

If I create a route which makes a few read write calls to Couchbase, what is the correct way to implement this in vert.x web?  By using the handler() method or the blockingHandler() method?

```
router.post("/some/path/").handler(routingContext -> {
  // a few read write calls to Couchbase here.
});
```

Also the same question again but under the context of generating web content from a template such as Handlebars or Pebble.  Use handler() or blockingHandler()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all depends on the kind of code you're writing inside the handler. Starting from your second questions first, all template engine handlers implement a asynchronous API (although loading the template itself is blocking but only done once due to the cache). In that case you should use:

```
router.post("/some/path/").handler(HandlebarsTemplateEngine.create());
```

Going back to the first question, if your couchbase client API is blocking, meaning that it is not responsive, it does block until you get a response back from the server, then in that case you must use `blockingHandler` or else you block the event loop and by extension block the whole application.

If however you're using couchbase async API then you should use the `handler` variant. For an example on how to use the async API see this blog [post](http://blog.couchbase.com/2015/december/couchbase-java-sdk-writing-vertx-verticle).